# Ember data 1.0.0 Beta: RESTAdapter endpoint customization no longer works

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am converting a project for use with Ember data 1.0.0 Beta 1 (just released).  I have a REST adapter listening on a specific endpoint and thus need to customize the endpoint.

This is how it worked in Ember data 0.13:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({})

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

In Ember data 0.13, the URL became: `https://api.example.com/authors`

In Ember data 1.0.0, the url becomes: `http://192.168.0.108:51939/authors`

with /192.168.0.108:51939 the url on which the webapp is running.

It thus looks like the url setting on .reopen of a RESTAdapter no longer works ?

I have the same problem with other customizations of the URL (such as namespace) ...

Hope somebody can help.

Marc

Comment: could you accept my answer?  i believe it is still correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this was updated soon after @cyclomarc's answer (check the PR https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1145).  In ember data 'url' is now 'host'.  'namespace' stills works.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  host: 'http://google.com',
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Sends requests to `http://google.com/api/*`

Ember v1.0.0-7

Ember Data v1.0.0-beta.1-17

EDIT: This is now documented in TRANSITION.md:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#host-and-namespace-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Ember-Data 1.0 beta is a complete rewrite of the API, see the [transition guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md), which details the changes made

[The transition guide mentions that the Adapter API has changed, and adapters will have to be rebuilt.](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#adapters) This is likely a breaking change, and the documentation is forthcoming on the endpoint customization

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a regression.  A PR is registered by Paul Chavard. 
See https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1145

In the meantime, overriding the buildUrl is a solution (see answer from @intuitivepixel)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://api.example.com',
  namespace: 'admin'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the links above.

Note that with the current ember-data beta you must call your custom adapter "App.***ApplicationAdapter***".

Doesn't work if you try "App.Adapter".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Having looked into the [transition guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md), still no mention about that `url` and `namespace` are removed from the `RESTAdapter`, further reading in the source code inline comments still refer it can be used as mentioned in the question. But as @cyclomarc mentioned in his comment (referring to what @tchak13 said that one should now use `buildURL`), so this is how you could do it overriding the `buildURL` function:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(type, id) {
    var url = "/" + Ember.String.pluralize(type.typeKey);
    if (id) { url += "/" + id; }

    return 'https://api.example.com' + url;
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems url and namespace options are no longer supported. I've got the recommendation to override buildUrl, but do not understand how to override the host and port in buildUrl.  I can use buildUrl to append for example .json to a request but not to modify the hostname or port.

Comment: @cyclomark, Really? I'll have to dig deeper into the latest merged PR's it seams strange to me that those properties are no longer supported... I'll get back to you soon

Comment: Thanks.  Got this info from Paul Chavard (@tchak13) whom I met during the Emberfest conf in Europe.

Comment: They are rebooting Ember Data, and it differs greatly from 0.13 https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: Yes, 1.0.0 beta is a reboot which should solve a lot of the 0.xx problems.  Transition document describes nothing about changes in the endpoint customization.  In the code, endpoint customization is still documented ... but thus no longer works.

Comment: Thx. Was just doing the same ...  Seems to be the only solution for now I guess.

Comment: @cyclomarc, seeing that the `buildURL` is just 3 LOC it's not that bad overriding it I guess

Answer (score 0):

It seems the RESTAdapter in beta1 has quite a few regressions.  I'm looking at it now and so far I see missing:

- namespace/url configuration
- camelCase to lower_with_underscore attribute mapping
- query params on GET url

Non of the above is mentioned in the transition guide (unless I completely missed it).

Comment: I have the same experience.  Lot of regression in this area and not documented what to do ...  Config of plurals also no longer works.